# Dots for abbreviating multiple arrows in quiver with tikz-cd

Tags: tikz-cd

I'd like to ask how to draw dots for abbreviating multiple arrows in quiver with tikz-cd. The following code is what I've tried to write so-called *n*-Kronecker quiver — the quiver with two vertices and *n* arrows from one to the other. The `\vdots` part doesn't work as I naively expected. Is it possible to draw vertical dots between the arrows *α*<sub>1</sub> and *α*<sub>2</sub>?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    1 \arrow[r, bend left, "\alpha_1"] \vdots \arrow[r, bend right, swap, "\alpha_n"] & 2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image: sample image]

Comment: Something like `\rar[draw=none,"\vdots"description]` will do. But you need to rescale the diagram properly.

Comment: @Symbol1 Thank you for your comment. It's getting closer to what I wanted. There is still some problems because the dots are slightly below the center and a small part of the above arrow disappears somehow. Is this a mere matter of scaling?

Comment: Well you can image that `\vdots` is too high so its background covers the upper arrow. Try combining `\raisebox` and `\smash` or so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to Symbol 1, I am now able to get the following desired result.

[image: n-Kronecker quiver]

Here is the code for this.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
    1
    \arrow[r, draw=none, "\raisebox{+1.5ex}{\vdots}" description]
    \arrow[r, bend left,        "\alpha_1"]
    \arrow[r, bend right, swap, "\alpha_n"]
    &
    2
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```